# Variable references the wrong iterator, even after confirmed reassignment

Tags: python

I have the following loop that reassigns to an iterator variable:

```
currentPrime = None
sieve = iter(range(2, 10))
while True:
    try:
        # The first value should be prime.
        currentPrime = next(sieve)
    except StopIteration:
        # Stop when sieve is empty.
        print(currentPrime)
        break
    print(currentPrime)
    # Filter out all multiples of currentPrime.
    sieve = (x for x in sieve if x % currentPrime)
    #print(tuple(sieve))
```

Even though I apply a filter on each iteration of the loop, the output goes through the entire range:

```
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
9
```

If I uncomment the last `print` call, I see `(3, 5, 7, 9)`, which means the filter and assignment to `sieve` work correctly, but the `next(sieve)` call somehow accesses the original iterator which no variable points to.

Any idea what's happening here? I'm using Python 3.7.0.

Comment: `currentPrime` is looked up on use, not on generator creation. We've got dupe targets around here somewhere...

Comment: Also, that is not a sieve. That's trial division. It's nowhere near as efficient as an actual sieve, even without the bug. See https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf

Comment: @user2357112: I posted an answer, but I didn't address your point about the algorithm, because it's tangential to the question, and because I don't know enough Haskell to understand much of what that paper says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user2357112 said, "`currentPrime` is looked up on use, not on generator creation."

One solution is to use `filter` with a lambda that localizes the current value of `currentPrime`. Note how the lambda uses a default argument to create a local variable:

```
currentPrime = None
sieve = iter(range(2, 10))
while True:
    try:
        # The first value should be prime.
        currentPrime = next(sieve)
    except StopIteration:
        # Stop when sieve is empty.
        print(currentPrime)
        break
    # Filter out all multiples of currentPrime.
    sieve = filter(lambda x, prime=currentPrime: x % prime, sieve)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a stack of generators if I'm not wrong.

What happens (TL;DR: all generators refer to one currentPrime instance and refer lazy):

1. Get value 2 from range iterator.
2. Create generator expression (A). Variable currentPrime = 2 now and is **NOT** free (not in closure). Generator consume rest of range (3..9).
3. Get value 3 from generator A (3 % 2 is True)
4. Create generator expression (B).  Variable currentPrime = 3 for **both** generators (A, B). Generator consume rest of generator A (4..9).
5. Get value 4 from generator B. See: next() → B.next(A) → A yields 4 (A checks: 4 % **3** is True), then B checks 4 % 3 is True.
6. Create generator expression (C) ... and so on.

Variable in in generator is not in closure, see:

```py
>>> a = 5
>>> gen = (a for i in range(3))
>>> a = 3
>>> list(gen)
[3, 3, 3]
```